# Finite difference formula to approximate second derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, computational-mathematics

I have one question which asks to derive a finite difference formula to approximate $f''(x)$ in the form of $$f''(x)\approx Af(x+2h)+Bf(x+h)+Cf(x)$$ with the method of undetermined coefficients.

Unfortunately, I don't understand what this question actually means. I'd appreciate if someone could clarify what exactly has to be done here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taylor expand $f(x+2h)$ and $f(x+h)$ about the point $x$. Choose $A,B,C$ so that the coefficient of $f(x)$ is zero, the coefficient of $f'(x)$ is zero, and the coefficient of $f''(x)$ is $1$. If possible you would also want to make the coefficients of higher derivatives be zero as well.

Comment: $f(x)$ is a general function, it's not given explicitly, only the form of $f''(x)$ is given. So, $f(x+2h) = f(x) + 2f'(x)h + 4\frac{f''(x)}{2!}h^2 + O(h^3)$ and $f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + \frac{f''(x)}{2!}h^2 + O(h^3)$, and there are no coefficients $A$, $B$ or $C$ here. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I mean that you do the expansions, multiply them by $A,B,C$ and add, then set up the equations I said and solve. So (presumably) $Af(x+2h)+Bf(x+h)+Cf(x)=(A+B+C)f(x)+(2A+B)hf'(x)+(2A+B/2)h^2f''(x)+O(h^3)=f''(x)+O(h^3)$ for appropriate $A,B,C$.

Comment: (It will actually turn out not to be $O(h^3)$ because $A,B,C$ will depend on $h$. Sorry if that confused you.)

Comment: So, we find $A, B, C$, but where's the finite difference formula in all this? Because it's the formula that needs to be found. Or is it $$f''(x)\approx Af(x+2h)+Bf(x+h)+Cf(x)$$ that is the formula? I think the form of the question itself is just confusing.

Comment: That's essentially the formula, yes, where "$\approx$" is to be made precise by the analysis.